# Whats an easy way to get the contents of a Google Spreadsheet as JSON using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whats an easy way to get the contents of a Google Spreadsheet as JSON using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Google Spreadsheet go to `Tools > Scripts > Script Editor`

Insert this code and hit the play button

```
function getValues() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(range.getValues())
  Browser.msgBox(json);
}​
```